# Object oriented circular button in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make a circular button in pygame.

I had made a class for the rectangle button. (below)
But I want to make it as a circle (and also other polygon).
I know there is no `get_cir` in `Surface` and it even doesn't work with it.
So how could I make it?

```
import pygame

class Button():

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width, height, normal_color, hovered_color,
                 label_color, font_type, font_size, command = None):

        self.text = text
        self.normal_color = normal_color
        self.hovered_color = hovered_color
        self.label_color = label_color
        self.font_type = font_type
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.command = command

        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(self.normal_color)

        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hovered.fill(self.hovered_color)

        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font_type, self.font_size)

        text_image = font.render(text, True, self.label_color)
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        self.image_normal.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        self.image_hovered.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

        self.hovered = False

    def update(self):
        if self.hovered:
            self.image = self.image_hovered
        else:
            self.image = self.image_normal

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.hovered == True:
                self.command()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can keep the (fast and efficient) rectangular collision detection, and when that indicates a click, then check the event's (x,y) position distance from the centre-point of the circle.

The [distance formula](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php) gives us a function:

```
def lineLength( pos1, pos2 ): 
    """Return the distance between the points (pos1) and (pos2)"""
    x1,y1 = pos1
    x2,y2 = pos2
    # length = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
    x_squared = ( x2 - x1 ) * ( x2 - x1 )
    y_squared = ( y2 - y1 ) * ( y2 - y1 )
    length = math.sqrt( x_squared + y_squared )
    return length
```

So then add an extra check to work out the distance between the centre of your button, and the mouse-click-point.  This should be less than the button's radius for the hover/click to be on the button:

```
def handle_event( self, event ):
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        self.hovered = False
        if ( self.rect.collidepoint( event.pos ) ):
            # check click is over the circular button ~
            radius = self.width / 2
            click_distance = lineLength( self.rect.center, event.pos )
            if ( click_distance <= radius ):
                self.hovered = True
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah @Furas' answer is better -  use the builtin `Vector2.distance_to()` instead of the function presented in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to draw circle or use image with circle. The only problem is to check mouse collision with circle object.

There is [sprite.collide_circle](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle) which uses circle areas to check collision between two sprites so you would need to create sprite with mouse position and check collision with button's sprite.

OR you can use circle definition

```
x**2 + y**2 =< R
```

so calculate distance between mouse and circle's center and it has to be equal or smaller then radius.

You can use even [pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) for this

---

For other figures the only idea is to use [sprite.collide_mask](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) which uses black&white bitmaps to check collisions between sprites. But it would need to create bitmap with filled figure and it can make problem if you want to draw polygon instead of use bitmap with polygon.